# Create all possible 1D lists from 2D list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

The idea is that I am creating a decision tree based on N different possible layers. Only certain layers will affect the outcome in some cases, For example:
[image]

In this example, the square can be the outcome of both LL and RL, so this could be represented by "ANY", L.

The problem is that as I can't (to the best of my knowledge) represent "ANY" in python, and the idea is that I will have a dictionary that represents the path to the outcome, i.e.

```
My_dict = {tuple(["ANY",L]): "Square"}
```

I have to create an array that looks like the following to represent the possibilities:

```
[[L,R], L]
```

I want to be able to go from this list to outputting two lists of the shape:

```
[L,L], [R,L]
```

To represent all possible paths that lead to the square.

I feel like this should be doable with the `itertools` module but I can't find anything myself, `itertools.permutations` simply returns the positional changes in the list, i.e. `[L,[L,R]]` and `[[L,R],L]`.

Any suggestions would be great. Keep in mind that the solution needs to work for various data types, i.e. in actuality the tree structure options could be booleans or integers rather than just left or right.

Comment: Check `itertools.product`.

Comment: unfortunately I have and haven't had any luck

Comment: How would the list look if the square was at LR and RL?

Comment: @tobias_k we're only considering the cases where one of the directions is irrelevant, in the case you mentioned both are relevant therefore in the master dictionary both options would be coded.

Comment: what about cycles? `[L, L]`, `[L, [L, L]]` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

data = [['L','R'], ['L']]
result = list(product(*data))
print(result)
```

---

```
[('L', 'L'), ('R', 'L')]
```

Comment: This only works because `"L"` is a single-character string; it would not work it it was, e.g. a number or a multi-character string. Does not have to be a problem, just saying. (Might be clearer when using `["LR", "L"]`, or `[["L", "R"], ["L"]]` though)

Comment: This also doesnt work for booleans, so in this case I want to use True and false to describe the position of the shapes.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Still isnt compatible with any other data data types as they arent iterables

Comment: by creating a function that wraps boolean values in brackets to make them iterables this now works.

Answer (score 0):

[still not sure on what do you want exactly]

Return all possible paths, included loops.

EDIT: for any data type

```
import itertools as it

def path_formatter(node):
    node1, node2 = node
    if len(node1) == 1:
        node1 = node1[0]
    if len(node2) == 1:
        node2 = node2[0]
    return node1, node2

p_lr = it.product('LR', repeat=2)
p_l = it.product('L', repeat=1)
p_r = it.product('R', repeat=1)

paths = map(path_formatter, it.combinations(it.chain(p_l, p_r, p_lr), r=2))
print(list(paths))
```

[original post - string only]
Here all the possible paths joining any node of any layer, as a list of strings.

```
import itertools as it


def formatter(lr_tuple):
    # format list of tuples to string
    l, r = lr_tuple
    if len(l) == 2:
        l = '[' + ','.join(l) + ']'
    if len(r) == 2:
        r = '[' + ','.join(r) + ']'
    return f'[{l},{r}]'


p_lr = it.product('LR', repeat=2)
p_l = it.product('L', repeat=1)
p_r = it.product('R', repeat=1)


nodes = [''.join(i) for i in it.chain(p_l, p_r, p_lr)]
nodes_pairs = it.combinations(nodes, r=2)


paths = map(formatter, nodes_pairs)

print(list(paths))
```

Output

```
# for any data type
[('L', 'R'), ('L', ('L', 'L')), ('L', ('L', 'R')), ('L', ('R', 'L')), ('L', ('R', 'R')), ('R', ('L', 'L')), ('R', ('L', 'R')), ('R', ('R', 'L')), ('R', ('R', 'R')), (('L', 'L'), ('L', 'R')), (('L', 'L'), ('R', 'L')), (('L', 'L'), ('R', 'R')), (('L', 'R'), ('R', 'L')), (('L', 'R'), ('R', 'R'))

# for string
['[L,R]', '[L,[L,L]]', '[L,[L,R]]', '[L,[R,L]]', '[L,[R,R]]', '[R,[L,L]]', '[R,[L,R]]', '[R,[R,L]]', '[R,[R,R]]', '[[L,L],[L,R]]', '[[L,L],[R,L]]', '[[L,L],[R,R]]', '[[L,R],[R,L]]', '[[L,R],[R,R]]', '[[R,L],[R,R]]']
```